Query between two dates
Is it possible to design the query formula so that the query narrows down a date range (column B)? The start date would be in F4 and the end date would be in G4
See my sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OdnjeYRJW7pt-rghcrP0xGQpSsD8j50ujVH5E2l0yYE/edit?usp=sharing

I recommend using FILTER for this:
=FILTER({LEFT(VA!B:B;10)\VA!AA:AA};"Yes"=VA!Y:Y;ISBETWEEN(--LEFT(VA!B:B;10);F4;G4))

